# Consider the following conditions on two proper non zero ideals $J_{1}$ and $J_{2}$ of non zero commutative ring R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Consider the following conditions on two proper non zero ideals $J_{1}$ and $J_{2}$ of non zero commutative ring R

P: for any $r_{1}, r_{2}\in R$ there exists a unique $r \ in R$ such that $r-r_{1}\in J_{1} $ and $r- r_{2}\in J_{2}$.

Q:$J_{1} +J_{2} =R$

Then which of the following is true?

A) P implies Q and  Q implies P

B) P implies Q and Q does not imply Q

C) P does not imply Q and Q implies P

D) neither P implies Q nor Q implies P.

By definition of ideal $r-r_{1}\in J_{1} $ and $r- r_{2}\in J_{2}$.
But what uniqneness of r has to do here. Which of the given option is true and how?
[A single correct option question of ring theory.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375581/a-single-correct-option-question-of-ring-theory)

Comment: What Uniqueness has to do here in P?

Comment: By including "unique" in the statement of $P$, it makes it possible to show that $Q$ does NOT imply $P$.  For if it happens that $0\neq x\in J_1\cap J_2$, then it's impossible for the $r$ in $P$ to be unique.